# obtaining PHP variable in jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

In my php file 'login_success.php', I have a the variable `$_COOKIE["user"]`

Would it be possible to return that variable within a jQuery Ajax statment such as this one. ive made a guess with Var UserName =:

```
function StartAjax(NameID){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login_success.php",
      cache: false,
      data: "name=Peter&location=Sheffield",
      success: function(html, status){
        $("#"+NameID).append(html);
        //$('#status').append(status);
        var userName = 

      } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
login_success.php:
echo $_COOKIE['user'];
```

Ajax asks for the page, returns the output/content (what is `echo`ed). Please note: Javascript is client side. PHP is server side. So you can't directly access PHP variables, but as done above, PHP can "give" the client the info it needs. If you're sending a lot of data, you can [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it for the ajax request. (you can learn about JSON on your own)

Also note, Javascript can access cookies, but I'm assuming this is just a sample question.

Comment: That's sound advice and i've managed to extract the data what I need using that method. Thanks mate